# Author information on all pages

Tags: pages, author

I want to post inforation about the author of the website on every page. This means it needs to display the 'author' avatar, name, biography (x chars) of **id 2**.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer myself:

```
<?php
$blogusers = get_users('include=2');
foreach ($blogusers as $user) {
    echo '<h3>Over '. $user->first_name .'</h3>'
    . get_user_meta($user->ID, 'description', true) .
    '';
}
?>
```